# All images uploading... except JPG files

Tags: assets, server, mamp

No idea why but my local install of CraftCMS (in a MAMP environment) won't let me upload JPGs. PNG, GIF, even TIFF works (just for the heck of it). When I select the file in the browser dialog, it closes then shows the loader bar and spinning gif anim. No progress is ever shown and the spinning continues eternally. http://cl.ly/image/1a2l1W2t1P1x

- Craft is up to date
- Uploads on remote install works perfectly
- Getting this error `net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` along with these details: http://cl.ly/image/3D2w1F2l2O1x
- Checked my php.ini file and it allows JPG uploads

I realize this may not even be an issue with Craft but a server side issue. I just have no idea how to troubleshoot this. Any help would be much appreciated!

I also checked my phperrors.log file and I got only this which is from back in early Dec and seemingly unrelated.

```
  [08-Dec-2014 02:47:37 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 9792 bytes) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sucasa/craft/app/vendor/imagine/imagine/lib/Imagine/Gd/Image.php on line 199
```

Comment: Check your `craft/storage/runtime/logs` files for any entries that begin with `[error]` or for the existence of a `phperrors.log` file, which will hold any PHP fatal errors.

Comment: Added my error (though seemingly unrelated) to the ticket. Thanks!

Comment: The same thing is happening to me. I've bumped my memory_limit up to 256MB, and checked my Craft logs for errors, but nothing jumps out. Has any one solved this issue?

Answer (score 13):

I had this same issue and resolved it (at the suggestion of Craft CMS support) by enabling ImageMagick in the php.ini and restarting MAMP PRO.

Per the MAMP PRO 3.0 user guide:

*The ImageMagick PHP module is included by default, but you must enable it inside the php.ini template file. Remove the ‘;’ from the following line.
;extension=imagick.so*

Comment: On MAMP PRO, enabling imagick solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks - same problem on MAMP PRO 4.1.1 and installing ImageMagick solved the problem. Thanks : )

Comment: Enabling Imagick solved this issue for me, also. **In MAMP 4, you can easily enable Imagick/ImageMagick under the "Extensions" checkboxes in the PHP settings.**

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue and solved it. This seems to be an issue with the exif lib. Try to disable mbstring overloading by setting

`mbstring.func_overload = 0`

to your php.ini or

`php_admin_value mbstring.func_overload 0`

in your apache virtual host configuration.

Hope that helps

-Oliver

Comment: That worked for me, thanks.  To layout some history.  I upgraded my linux server to a dedicated.  Including mysql 5.7 (mariadb 10.2.8), nginx, centos 7.3, php 7.1.  After all that, I discovered a few odd things like this image upload issue.  So it's something of an odd issue but whatever it is, the solution works.

Answer (score 4):

I kept bumping into the same kind of issue. Even when I applied a fix mentioned here or in another topic. After a while the same issue would arise again.

What finally did the trick for me - in MAMP, was to add additional parameters to the host-file.

In MAMP, select the desired host. On the right side choose the Extended tab. Where it says 'Additional parameters for ' add this line:

*AddHandler fastcgi-script .fcgi*

This looks a lot like [the solution mentioned here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/4661/fastcgi-error-when-accessing-a-local-development-site-using-mamp-pro), but for some reason it didn't stick.

Restart server (in later versions MAMP restarts itself) and you should be good to go!

Answer (score 1):

From your error, I think the fact that only JPG files are failing is a coincidence.

Perhaps when you were testing the PNG, GIF and TIFF files were all relatively small, but the JPG files were large enough to bump you over the 32MB limit assigned to PHP in your `php.ini` file.

Regardless, if you open up your `php.ini` file, find the `memory_limit` setting, and bump it up to 128MB (or 256MB if you're feeling saucy), the problem should go away.

You might have to restart your web server before that setting takes effect.

Comment: I only wish this were the case... no matter the size .jpg files don't work. I've tried .jpgs at 100kb and 20mb and get the same issue.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue with devMode enabled, zip up your `craft/storage/runtime/logs` folder and send it to support@buildwithcraft.com?  I'll update here with anything we find.