# Assets on localhost

Tags: assets

I'm running Craft with MAMP under this file system path:

```
craft/
public_html/
    index.php
    img/uploads/
```

Via Settings > Assets, I have set the following paths:

[image: Craft CMS Assets Settings]

I've also tried this path under "URL":

```
http://localhost:8888/project_name/craft/public_html/img/uploads/
```

When I go to upload an image, the loading bar is stuck at 100% and nothing uploads. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the problem wasn't down to the asset paths.

After setting the original paths from my question, I was able to upload PNG files, but not JPEGs.

You need to [enable ImageMagick in php.ini on MAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13201071/how-to-install-image-magick-for-mamp-pro-on-mountain-lion-10-8-2) for Craft to accept JPEG uploads.

See [this answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/5415/all-images-uploading-except-jpg-files) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Try access your asset by this URL:

```
http://localhost:8888/img/uploads/
```