# Assets not uploading but will update manually on local server

Tags: assets

Site is running on MAMP PRO locally.

PHP settings:
max_execution_time = 60
memory_limit = 128M
upload_max_filesize = 32M
post_max_size = 32M

I have an Asset source set-up as:

> File system Path: "{basePath}images/main-content/"
>
> URL: "{baseUrl}images/main-content/"

In my craft/config/general I have Environment-Specific Variables as per the Craft docs http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/multi-environment-configs

When I upload an image the progress bar goes across but then stays on screen with the spinner constantly spinning. The files never upload.

If I manually drop an image in the images/main-content folder then do "Update Asset Indexes" in Settings the image appears in Assets OK.

"Images" and "main-content" are set to 777
The files aren't particularly big.

No errors in PHP logs.

Where else should I look

Comment: If you look at the network tab in your browser's inspector and look at the response for that request, does it have anything in it?

Comment: Ah. 500 Internal Server Error. The server encountered an internal error or
misconfiguration and was unable to complete
your request. What should I check? @BradBell

Comment: Search in your `craft/storage/runtime/logs` folder for `[error]` and see if the error is logged there.

Comment: There are some errors in there but I don't know if they're related. @BradBell

Comment: 2015/03/02 22:33:02 [trace] [system.db.CDbCommand] Querying SQL: SELECT count(`id`)
FROM `craft_tasks`
WHERE (level = 0) AND (status = :status). Bound with :status='error'
in /Users/timprint/Dropbox/Sites/nailcote-responsive/craft/app/etc/db/DbCommand.php (90)
in /Users/timprint/Dropbox/Sites/nailcote-responsive/craft/app/services/TasksService.php (478)
in /Users/timprint/Dropbox/Sites/nailcote-responsive/craft/app/variables/TasksVariable.php (56)

Comment: 2015/03/02 22:33:02 [profile] [system.db.CDbCommand.query] begin:system.db.CDbCommand.query(SELECT count(`id`)
FROM `craft_tasks`
WHERE (level = 0) AND (status = :status). Bound with :status='error')

Comment: 2015/03/02 22:33:02 [profile] [system.db.CDbCommand.query] end:system.db.CDbCommand.query(SELECT count(`id`)
FROM `craft_tasks`
WHERE (level = 0) AND (status = :status). Bound with :status='error')

Comment: Those are all `[profile]` and `[trace]` entries. Search specifically for `[error]`.

Comment: Nothing with [error] @BradBell

Comment: Must be an Apache 500 internal server error, then. Try checking Apache's error logs.

Comment: [Mon Mar 02 22:51:07 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] FastCGI: incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server "/Applications/MAMP/fcgi-bin/php5.4.34.fcgi", referer: http://nailcote-responsive:8888/admin/assets

Comment: Sounds like a MAMP bug? Are you on the latest version?

Comment: I am - 3.0.7.3 I'll have a search around for MAMP issues and see if I can find anything. Thanks @BradBell

Comment: I found a fix for this in another post.

http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/4661/fastcgi-error-when-accessing-a-local-development-site-using-mamp-pro

Comment: Ahh, awesome.  I'll vote to mark this as a duplicate and reference the other one. Thanks for the follow up!