# Can't get past the install on local MAMP Pro install... "Oops screen"

Tags: error, installation

Can't seem to get past the install screen for some reason or other... I fill in the relevant information, it starts to install then I get the OOPS screen... I looked in the log and I'm seeing the following ...

```
[Mon May 11 13:25:08 2015] [error] [client ::1] FastCGI: comm with server "/Applications/MAMP/fcgi-bin/php5.3.29.fcgi" aborted: idle timeout (30 sec), referer: http://travelexperience/admin/install
[Mon May 11 13:25:08 2015] [error] [client ::1] FastCGI: incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server "/Applications/MAMP/fcgi-bin/php5.3.29.fcgi", referer: http://travelexperience/admin/install
```

But I have no idea what's up...

**UPDATE**

Okay I'm getting the following error in the craft log...

```
2015/05/11 12:48:19 [warning] [application] Skipping record /sites/travelexperience/craft/app/records/BaseRecord.php because it’s abstract or an interface.
```

Comment: Have you made sure you meet the minimum server requirements? These can be found [here](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/requirements). Alternatively you could run [this tool](https://github.com/putyourlightson/craft-requirements) which will check for you.

Comment: You're hitting a timeout. Does the answer of http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/4661/fastcgi-error-when-accessing-a-local-development-site-using-mamp-pro help to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

See this answer for how to work around the MAMP `incomplete headers` bug: https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/6573/57

The `[warning] [application] Skipping record...` log entry isn't an error at all and is completely normal to see during installation.