# Getting a "500 Internal Server Error" when uploading an image asset

Tags: assets

Just giving Craft CMS a test drive. Setup a local site using MAMP Pro. Got the basic site up and running ok, admin as well. Then i wanted to try out image assets, so I created an Asset Source for images, local folder. Created my "images" folder under the public dir, and specified "images/" as the file system path for my asset source. Added an image transform.

Then I try and upload an image, and it fails, with the ajax call "/index.php/admin/actions/assets/uploadFile" returning a 500 error. I tried checking the log files but there are no error messages relating to this failed ajax call.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: If you don't see the underlying error message in `craft/storage/runtime/logs`, try checking Apache's error log files.  Maybe it's a permissions issue on the `images` folder?

Comment: true! i should've checked before posting. but unfortunately nothing in the apache error log (/Applications/MAMP/logs/apache_error.log). then tried all sorts of permissions on the images directory: 700, 770, 777, 775, 755, and none of them worked. on other local dev sites where i upload image files 755 has worked (with apache running as exactly the same user etc). running out of options...

Comment: am i right in thinking i can use a relative path for the asset source ("images/") if that dir exists underneath the public dir?

Comment: Yeah, that should be fine.  Maybe try changing it to an absolute path just to rule things out?

Comment: yeh, did that but to no avail :(

Comment: If you try the upload with your browser's inspector's network tab open, then check the response for the AJAX call where the upload occurs, does it return anything useful?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26144/discussion-between-bhu-boue-vidya-and-brad-bell).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ok i solved the problem by following the answer to this question here:

[FastCGI error when accessing a local development site using MAMP Pro](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/4661/fastcgi-error-when-accessing-a-local-development-site-using-mamp-pro)

even though the ajax call didn't generate an apache error at the moment it was called, it must have been something to do with fastcgi in general, cos the answer to that question worked for me!

i have never had this problem before, and i have heaps of other local sites which also do file/image uploading. so strange. and uploading of other file types (eg pdf) into the assets area worked no problem! doesn't make sense. but as a developer, sometimes you just accept the mystery of it all...

#### UPDATE

the problem started rearing it's ugly head again, even though i hadn't touched the `httpd.conf` edit i did to fix it. so i just deactivated the fastcgi module on the MAMP Pro dashboard. et voila, we're back in business....

Comment: Ahh, nice catch.  Got to be some weird MAMP bug, I suspect.

Comment: Great find. Such a random error. You saved me hours of troubleshooting. Many thanks!