# Image Upload "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)"

Tags: image

I'm getting my nerves on this because I can't find what's stopping from uploading. I simply choose a file, the loading show and get itself complete, but it simply stops at the 100%. I ran into my browser's console and this shows up:

Safari:
**"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)"**

Chrome:
"Failed to load resource: **http://craft.dev/index.php/admin/actions/assets/uploadFile** the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)"

Please help me to figure this out... A huge thanks in advance!

I'm running the website on localhost and using AMPPS and Navicat for the DB.

Comment: Dupe? https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/10670/getting-a-500-internal-server-error-when-uploading-an-image-asset

Comment: Anything logged in your `craft/storage/runtime/logs` folder or your Apache error logs?

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

Got an answer here. It was me the problem the whole long. I read through my error logs (thanks Brad on that!) and found out that I had that the my php's gd extension wasn't active. I activated and I now have it working! 
Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Glad you're sorted, João and thanks for the follow-up.

Comment: @João Gonçalves can you explain, how exactly you activated it? I run into the same problem but don't know how to activate the gd extension.