# Getting stuck in "Oops" on install with MAMP PRO

Tags: installation, mamp

I can't get through the install process using MAMP PRO. Here is the log from `storage/runtime/logs`:

```
2016/05/03 00:10:22 [error] [exception.Craft\HttpException.503] exception 'Craft\HttpException' in /Users/amsiMac/craftCMS/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php:934
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/amsiMac/craftCMS/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php(242): Craft\WebApp->_processUpdateLogic()
#1 /Users/amsiMac/craftCMS/craft/app/framework/base/CApplication.php(185): Craft\WebApp->processRequest()
#2 /Users/amsiMac/craftCMS/craft/app/index.php(62): CApplication->run()
#3 /Users/amsiMac/craftCMS/public/index.php(19): require_once('/Users/amsiMac/...')
#4 {main}
REQUEST_URI=/index.php/admin/actions/users/getAuthTimeout?dontExtendSession=1
HTTP_REFERER=http://mycraft/admin/dashboard
---

******************************************************************************************************
2016/05/03 00:11:22 [error] [exception.Craft\HttpException.503] exception 'Craft\HttpException' in /Users/amsiMac/craftCMS/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php:934
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/amsiMac/craftCMS/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php(242): Craft\WebApp->_processUpdateLogic()
#1 /Users/amsiMac/craftCMS/craft/app/framework/base/CApplication.php(185): Craft\WebApp->processRequest()
#2 /Users/amsiMac/craftCMS/craft/app/index.php(62): CApplication->run()
#3 /Users/amsiMac/craftCMS/public/index.php(19): require_once('/Users/amsiMac/...')
#4 {main}
REQUEST_URI=/index.php/admin/actions/users/getAuthTimeout?dontExtendSession=1
HTTP_REFERER=http://mycraft/admin/dashboard
---

******************************************************************************************************
2016/05/03 00:11:32 [error] [exception.Craft\HttpException.503] exception 'Craft\HttpException' in /Users/amsiMac/craftCMS/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php:798
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/amsiMac/craftCMS/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php(203): Craft\WebApp->_processInstallRequest()
#1 /Users/amsiMac/craftCMS/craft/app/framework/base/CApplication.php(185): Craft\WebApp->processRequest()
#2 /Users/amsiMac/craftCMS/craft/app/index.php(62): CApplication->run()
#3 /Users/amsiMac/craftCMS/public/index.php(19): require_once('/Users/amsiMac/...')
#4 {main}
REQUEST_URI=/
---

******************************************************************************************************
2016/05/03 00:12:23 [error] [exception.Craft\HttpException.503] exception 'Craft\HttpException' in /Users/amsiMac/craftCMS/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php:934
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/amsiMac/craftCMS/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php(242): Craft\WebApp->_processUpdateLogic()
#1 /Users/amsiMac/craftCMS/craft/app/framework/base/CApplication.php(185): Craft\WebApp->processRequest()
#2 /Users/amsiMac/craftCMS/craft/app/index.php(62): CApplication->run()
#3 /Users/amsiMac/craftCMS/public/index.php(19): require_once('/Users/amsiMac/...')
#4 {main}
REQUEST_URI=/index.php/admin/actions/users/getAuthTimeout?dontExtendSession=1
HTTP_REFERER=http://mycraft/admin/dashboard
---

******************************************************************************************************
2016/05/03 00:12:05 [warning] [application] Skipping record /Users/amsiMac/craftCMS/craft/app/records/BaseRecord.php because it’s abstract or an interface.

******************************************************************************************************
```

I have all the folder permissions set to 777 and followed [these directions](http://blog-en.mamp.info/2010/02/how-to-set-mysql-default-storage-engine.html) to make sure InnoDB was being used

**Update** new log in devMode

```
2016/05/03 00:55:17 [error] [exception.Craft\HttpException.503] Craft\HttpException in /Users/amsiMac/craftCMS/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php:798
2016/05/03 00:55:17 [trace] [system.CModule] Loading "errorHandler" application component
in /Users/amsiMac/craftCMS/craft/app/etc/errors/ErrorHandler.php (281)
2016/05/03 00:55:19 [error] [exception.Craft\HttpException.503] Craft\HttpException in /Users/amsiMac/craftCMS/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php:934
2016/05/03 00:55:19 [trace] [system.CModule] Loading "errorHandler" application component
in /Users/amsiMac/craftCMS/craft/app/etc/errors/ErrorHandler.php (281)
in /Users/amsiMac/craftCMS/craft/app/etc/errors/ErrorHandler.php (281)
2016/05/03 00:55:47 [error] [exception.Craft\HttpException.503] Craft\HttpException in /Users/amsiMac/craftCMS/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php:934
2016/05/03 00:55:47 [trace] [system.CModule] Loading "errorHandler" application component
in /Users/amsiMac/craftCMS/craft/app/etc/errors/ErrorHandler.php (281)
in /Users/amsiMac/craftCMS/craft/app/etc/errors/ErrorHandler.php (281)
2016/05/03 00:55:58 [error] [exception.Craft\HttpException.503] Craft\HttpException in /Users/amsiMac/craftCMS/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php:934
2016/05/03 00:55:58 [trace] [system.CModule] Loading "errorHandler" application component
in /Users/amsiMac/craftCMS/craft/app/etc/errors/ErrorHandler.php (281)
in /Users/amsiMac/craftCMS/craft/app/etc/errors/ErrorHandler.php (281)
2016/05/03 00:56:20 [error] [exception.Craft\HttpException.503] Craft\HttpException in /Users/amsiMac/craftCMS/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php:934
2016/05/03 00:56:20 [trace] [system.CModule] Loading "errorHandler" application component
in /Users/amsiMac/craftCMS/craft/app/etc/errors/ErrorHandler.php (281)
in /Users/amsiMac/craftCMS/craft/app/etc/errors/ErrorHandler.php (281)
2016/05/03 00:56:47 [error] [exception.Craft\HttpException.503] Craft\HttpException in /Users/amsiMac/craftCMS/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php:934
2016/05/03 00:56:47 [trace] [system.CModule] Loading "errorHandler" application component
in /Users/amsiMac/craftCMS/craft/app/etc/errors/ErrorHandler.php (281)
in /Users/amsiMac/craftCMS/craft/app/etc/errors/ErrorHandler.php (281)
2016/05/03 00:56:59 [error] [exception.Craft\HttpException.503] Craft\HttpException in /Users/amsiMac/craftCMS/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php:934
2016/05/03 00:56:59 [trace] [system.CModule] Loading "errorHandler" application component
in /Users/amsiMac/craftCMS/craft/app/etc/errors/ErrorHandler.php (281)
in /Users/amsiMac/craftCMS/craft/app/etc/errors/ErrorHandler.php (281)
    `status` ENUM('pending','error','running') NULL,
    `status` ENUM('pending','error','running') NULL,
    `status` ENUM('pending','error','running') NULL,
2016/05/03 00:57:03 [info] [application] Creating the deprecationerrors table.
2016/05/03 00:57:03 [trace] [system.db.CDbCommand] Executing SQL: CREATE TABLE `craft_deprecationerrors` (
2016/05/03 00:57:03 [profile] [system.db.CDbCommand.execute] begin:system.db.CDbCommand.execute(CREATE TABLE `craft_deprecationerrors` (
2016/05/03 00:57:03 [profile] [system.db.CDbCommand.execute] end:system.db.CDbCommand.execute(CREATE TABLE `craft_deprecationerrors` (
2016/05/03 00:57:03 [trace] [system.db.CDbCommand] Executing SQL: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `craft_deprecationerrors_key_fingerprint_unq_idx` ON `craft_deprecationerrors` (`key`, `fingerprint`)
2016/05/03 00:57:03 [profile] [system.db.CDbCommand.execute] begin:system.db.CDbCommand.execute(CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `craft_deprecationerrors_key_fingerprint_unq_idx` ON `craft_deprecationerrors` (`key`, `fingerprint`))
2016/05/03 00:57:03 [profile] [system.db.CDbCommand.execute] end:system.db.CDbCommand.execute(CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `craft_deprecationerrors_key_fingerprint_unq_idx` ON `craft_deprecationerrors` (`key`, `fingerprint`))
2016/05/03 00:57:03 [info] [application] Finished creating the deprecationerrors table.
2016/05/03 00:57:08 [error] [system.db.CDbCommand] CDbCommand::fetchAll() failed: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'craft_test.elements.type' isn't in GROUP BY. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT `elements`.`id`, `elements`.`type`, `elements`.`enabled`, `elements`.`archived`, `elements`.`dateCreated`, `elements`.`dateUpdated`, `elements_i18n`.`slug`, `elements_i18n`.`uri`, `elements_i18n`.`enabled` AS `localeEnabled`, `content`.`id` AS `contentId`, `content`.`title`, `content`.`field_body`, `entries`.`sectionId`, `entries`.`typeId`, `entries`.`authorId`, `entries`.`postDate`, `entries`.`expiryDate`, `structureelements`.`root`, `structureelements`.`lft`, `structureelements`.`rgt`, `structureelements`.`level`
2016/05/03 00:57:08 [error] [exception.CDbException] CDbException: CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'craft_test.elements.type' isn't in GROUP BY. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT `elements`.`id`, `elements`.`type`, `elements`.`enabled`, `elements`.`archived`, `elements`.`dateCreated`, `elements`.`dateUpdated`, `elements_i18n`.`slug`, `elements_i18n`.`uri`, `elements_i18n`.`enabled` AS `localeEnabled`, `content`.`id` AS `contentId`, `content`.`title`, `content`.`field_body`, `entries`.`sectionId`, `entries`.`typeId`, `entries`.`authorId`, `entries`.`postDate`, `entries`.`expiryDate`, `structureelements`.`root`, `structureelements`.`lft`, `structureelements`.`rgt`, `structureelements`.`level`
2016/05/03 00:57:08 [trace] [system.CModule] Loading "errorHandler" application component
```

Comment: Are you on MAMP PRO 3.5?

Comment: yes I am using MAMP PRO 3.5

Comment: Can you nuke any existing tables in the database, nuke `craft/storage/runtime/logs`, enable [devMode](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#devMode) and try the install again? If it fails again, search the `craft.log` file for `[error]` and see if there is anything.

Comment: Ok I did that. New log has been added to the question

Comment: Welp, that's odd.  You're doing this with the latest files from https://craftcms.com I assume?

Comment: Yes I was using files I had just downloaded that day.

Comment: If you open up your my.cnf MAMP template and search for `sql_mode`, do you find it and if so, what's the value?

Answer (score 1):

I am answering this to report that I did get it working and to collect the links describing edits needed in the my.cnf and httpd.conf files in one place.

I got it working earlier today by starting over completely with a new server in MAMP Pro, a new db created in PHPMyAdmin, and a freshly downloaded set of files from craftcms.com

- I made the file permissions to 777 as needed
- Re-edited the https.conf file as described [here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/6573/5089) and
- reran the tests to make sure [InnoDB was available](http://blog-en.mamp.info/2010/02/how-to-set-mysql-default-storage-engine.html)

I have no idea why it wasn't working the other day.

Comment: I would not recommend running your craft install at `chmod 777`. You should be able to set these properly by looking at this article: http://ifmeister.com/mamp-file-permissions-for-a-local-development-environment/ hope it helps and happy Crafting!