# Problem uploading JPG in MAMP Pro 4.2 (9213)

Tags: assets, mamp

I use MAMP Pro for a few years in combination with Craft CMS, but since the new upgrade to version 4 I cannot upload JPGs anymore. Dit anybody had the same issue and how to fix this?

In the PHP7.0.20.ini there's a line says:

```
MAMP_Imagick_MAMPextension=imagick.so
```

And these are the settings for resource limits:

```
max_execution_time = 240
max_input_time = 240
memory_limit = 1024M 
upload_max_filesize = 32M
```

But it's different from earlier versions, so it looks like ImageMagick is loaded?

Thanks in advance.

Cheers, Martijn

Comment: Is there anything showing in the Craft logs under Storage > Runtime?
Image upload problems wouldn't be related to GD or Imagick specifically as they aren't responsible for the upload, it's more likely a permissions problem. I have a number of different environments, MAMP being one of them and have uploads working correctly.

Comment: No, when I try to upload a JPG the progress bar fills up and freezes. Nothing appear in the log. And PNG files can be uploaded right away.

Comment: When I check the logs in MAMP I see this error in the appache_error.log: 

    [Tue Aug 15 15:00:56 2017] [error] [client ::1] FastCGI: incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server "/Applications/MAMP/fcgi-bin/php7.0.20.fcgi", referer: http://craftcmsdeluxe.dev/admin/assets

Answer (score 5):

I found the answer: in the main window of MAMP Pro there's a sidebar with a sub heading Languages > PHP. When you click that and check the option under Extensions: Imagick / ImageMagick, all my problems disappear and I can upload JPG and PNG.

Comment: Haha. Unreal that is was this easy! Thanks a lot my man.